# I cannot retrieve data from PowerBi Integration after reopening PowerApps

Tags: powerbi, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I have launched a PowerApps from PowerBi and after saving I cannot see the same data in the PowerApps Editor and PowerBi. At the beginning I could see data in both. I refreshed PowerBi report. Any idea? Pictures below:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to refresh your cache for powerapps.
I usually save my powerapps (Editor) close the browser and open it again. Once you do that you shall see your refreshed data.

You could also user ctrl+F5 to refresh cache.

> If you are running the app in the browser then you need to clear out
>   the browser cache or simply by hard refreshing your browser by
>   pressing CTRL and F5 you can force PowerApp to reload data.
>
> If you are running App in PowerApp from your mobile, IPad or Tablet
>   you need to open the PowerApp mobile application, Click on three lines
>   menu from the left top corner, click on 'clear cache' menu and click
>   on 'Confirm' button.
>
> That will clear out the cache for the app.

[Ref Article](https://cielocosta.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024726591-How-do-I-clear-the-cache-in-Microsoft-PowerApps-)